# apply a this to a jQuery callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I want something to trigger when a bootstrap modal closes. There is a listener for that: `modal.on('hidden', function(){`...`})`
My problem is that I want to change the value of an object I can only reference using `this`, but inside the modal callback, `this` refers to the modal. Here is how my code looks:

```
return {
 bool: false,

 openModal: function(modal) {
  modal.open();

  // this part doesn't work because this refers to the jQ modal object instead of the current object
  modal.on('hidden', function() { this.bool = true; });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
openModal: function(modal) {
  modal.open();

  var that = this;
  modal.on('hidden', function() { that.bool = true; });
 }
```

Comment: in 7 minutes I will be able to accept this answer. Thank you, and I hate myself.